# How to get write access to Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, script, app, javascript

I am trying to use Stack Exchange API to post upvotes and downvotes from my app. I have received the access token but not sure what to do with write_access

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.